Where did Geordi's eyes go?
In Star Trek: The Next Generation, Geordi regrows his eyes at the end of "All Good Things" in season 7, but he is wearing his visor in the film Generations. What happened to his eyes?

It's been a long time since I saw the episode... but wasn't that a Geordi from a timeline that ceased to be?

"where no eyeball has gone before"?

In "All Good Things," Picard found his consciousness shifting, seemingly at random, between present (2370), past (2364, during the events of "Encounter at Farpoint") and future (circa 2395) versions of himself.
In all three time periods, he investigated a mysterious spatial anomaly located in the Devron System in the Neutral Zone. When the Enterprise-D approached the anomaly in 2370, the anomaly was determined to be an eruption of anti-time, sending out waves of temporal energy which disrupted the normal flow of time. As a result of this, Crusher discovered that La Forge's optic nerves were regenerating, as if he were growing new eyes.

CRUSHER: This is amazing. The DNA in his optic nerves is regenerating. Geordi, it's as if you're growing new eyes.
PICARD: How is this possible?
CRUSHER: It shouldn't be possible at all. There's no medical explanation for spontaneous regeneration of an organ.
OGAWA: Doctor we've just gotten reports from two crew members who say they have old scars which are healing themselves.
DATA: Captain, I believe I have a partial explanation. I have completed my analysis of the anomaly. It appears to be a multi-phasic temporal convergence in the space-time continuum.
CRUSHER: In English, Data.
DATA: It is, in essence, an eruption of anti-time.
PICARD: Anti-time?
DATA: A relatively new concept in temporal mechanics. The relationship between anti-time and normal time is analogous to the relationship between antimatter and normal matter.
PICARD: So if time and anti-time were to collide
DATA: They would annihilate one other, causing a rupture in space. I believe this is what happened in the Devron system. The rupture may be sending out waves of temporal energy which are disrupting the normal flow of time.

Later in the episode, La Forge was shown operating a console at the science station on the bridge of the Enterprise without his VISOR on, indicating that his biological eyes were fully functional at this point.



Near the end of the episode, the anomaly was collapsed when the three versions of the Enterprise-D from the past, present and future entered it and remained there while generating static warp shells. However, this took a toll on each ship and the versions of the ship from 2364 and 2370 were destroyed by warp core breaches, meaning that the version of La Forge with the regenerated optic nerves actually died in this scene.
Picard then has a chat with Q and is sent back to a point in time corresponding to the beginning of the episode. This is evident by an interaction he has with Worf and Troi that mirrors one he had with them in the opening scene.
Scene with Picard, Worf and Troi from the beginning of the episode:

PICARD: Counsellor! What's today's date? The date!
WORF: Stardate 47988.
PICARD: 47988.
TROI: Captain, what's wrong?
PICARD: 47988. I'm not sure. I don't know how or why, but I'm moving back and forth through time.


Scene with Picard, Worf and Troi from near the end of the episode:

TROI: Captain, are you all right?
PICARD: Mister Worf, what's the date?
WORF: Stardate 47988.
TROI: Is something wrong, sir?
PICARD: No. No. No. I think I'll get back to bed. I could use some sleep.


Since Picard was sent back to a point in time corresponding to the beginning of the episode, that means La Forge's optic nerves hadn't been regenerated by the anomaly yet. And since Picard subsequently learns that the anomaly doesn't exist now, that means La Forge's optic nerves would never be regenerated in this new version of the present.

PICARD: Captain's log, supplemental. Starfleet Command reports no unusual activity along the Neutral Zone, and there is no sign of a temporal anomaly. It would appear that I am the only member of the crew to retain any knowledge of the events I experienced.

In other words, everything Picard experienced in all three time periods prior to this scene occurred in what can now be considered alternate timelines which are non-canon from this point forward. It was already established in the first half of the episode that they weren't even canon to one another.

DATA: It would appear there is a discontinuity between the time periods you described. Events in one time period would seem to have no effect on the other two.

In the new timeline that began in the second scene with Picard, Worf and Troi, La Forge never regained the use of his biological eyes and continued to rely on his VISOR until he acquired ocular implants some time between Star Trek: Generations (1994) and Star Trek: First Contact (1996). Accordingly, he's shown wearing his VISOR in the final scene of the episode.




It feels like this episode should end with “… and then I woke up”.

@Janus Bahs Jacquet - Well, there are fans who think/suspect that much of what Q does with his powers is merely illusion, so those people probably would interpret most of Picard's experiences in this episode as being no more real than a dream. I considered adding that alternate interpretation to the end of my answer, but I didn't want to confuse matters and don't subscribe to that theory myself.

The episode TNG: All Good Things takes place on three separate time periods;

2364 A.D. (just after Picard came on board the Enterprise).

2370 A.D., (which is the date and time you'd expect to see in a Season 7 episode of TNG).

Circa 2395 A.D. (which is the time period in which you see Geordi with his regrown eyes).


Even if we ignore that the 'future timeline' in All Good Things was cancelled out by Picard's actions, the film Star Trek: Generations takes place in 2371, just one year after the end of Star Trek TNG Season 7, and presumably before he decided to get his eyes sorted.

The last time we Geordi in 'the present day' of 2370, he's still sporting his VISOR




Huh. I guess was right about it being a version from a different time.

The OP isn't asking about future Geordi getting "his eyes sorted" (as will actually happen some time before First Contact), but about present-day Geordi involuntarily growing an optical nerve under the effect of the anomaly for some reason.

The version of Geordi in (circa) 2395 appeared to have ocular implants rather than normal eyes.
